# JavaScript : Rearrange array elements according to the absolute difference with x

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, absolute

Rearrange array elements according to the absolute difference with **x**  i. e., the element having a minimum difference comes first and so on. Like I'm taking 
array  **[10, 5, 3, 9, 2, 3]** and **x = 7** then the absolute difference for every element should be =

```
7 - 10 = 3(abs)
7 - 5 = 2
7 - 3 = 4
7 - 9 = 2(abs)
7 - 2 = 5
7 - 3 = 4
```

So according to the difference with X, elements are arranged as **[5,9,10,3,3,2]**.

I have tried this by the code below but still failing to do so:

```js
function ar(a, x) {
  var obj = {}, d, i, res;

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    d = Math.abs(a[i] - x);
    obj[a[i]] = d;
  }
  
  res = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[a] - obj[b]
  });
  
  for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res[i] = parseInt(res[i]);
  }
  
  return res;
}

var o = ar([10, 5, 3, 9, 2, 3], 7);
console.log(o);
```

as you can see I'm making object which have only one key but values repeat here .. I can't find another way of solving it the answer I get is **[5,9,10,3,2]**:(..

Comment: Objects can't have duplicate properties, so when you repeat a property it overrides the previous one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> as you can see I'm making object which have only one key but values
>   repeat here

Objects can't have duplicate properties, so when you repeat a property it overrides the previous one with new value

You can simply use sort with `Math.abs`

```js
let arr = [10, 5, 3, 9, 2, 3]
let x = 7

let sortByDiff = (arr,x) => arr.sort((a,b)=> Math.abs(a-x) - Math.abs(b-x))

console.log(sortByDiff(arr,x))
```

Comment: can you please explain how does it work coz I'm not getting it although your answer is correct..

Comment: @Anonymus instead of sorting based on value here we are passing absolute difference to compareFunction of sort, you can read [Sort MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)  for reference how sort works

Answer (score 2):

Just define your distance function:

```js
const dist = x => Math.abs(x - 7);
```

and pass the difference of it applied to both argument of the `sort` method.

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => dist(a) - dist(b));
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more info on the `sort` method.

```js
const arr = [10, 5, 3, 9, 2, 3];
const dist = x => Math.abs(x - 7);
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => dist(a) - dist(b));

console.log(sorted);
```